# ZGrep for first occurence of pattern *after* given line

Tags: awk, grep, zgrep

so I know that to find the line number of the first occurrence of a pattern in a file I do:

```
zgrep -n -m 1 "pattern" big_file.txt.gz
```

but what If I want to skip the first 500K lines?
(I can't decompress the file. It's too large.)

Comment: Try: `gzcat big_file.txt.gz | awk 'NR > 500000 && /pattern/ {print NR ":" $0; exit}'`

Comment: thanks again. It works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gzcat | awk` command:

```sh
gzcat big_file.txt.gz |
awk 'NR > 500000 && /pattern/ {print NR ":" $0; exit}'
```

Comment: On some Unix version `gzcat` is different from `zcat`. `gzcat` is for `.gz` files and `zcat` is for `.z` (zipped) files